# Is it possible to add an Azure Data Factory pipeline runid to an Azure Data Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Within my ADF Data Flow I want to add the pipeline runID as a column. It is not possible within the Data Flow to add a dynamic value referring to the pipeline runId.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add a parameter in Data Flow and set it's value as `@pipeline().RunId`. Then create a DerivedColumn activity and add a column which's value is `$pipelineRunId`.

Details:

1.create a parameter in Data Flow.
[image]

2.set this parameter's value.
[image]

3.create a DerivedColumn activity and add a column.
[image]